# Question about connection by private key with python fabric

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric, private-key

How I can specify pass phrase for my Connection with private key? I didn't find anything about this in fabric documentation.

Here is my connection:

```
c = Connection(host="host",user="usr",connect_kwargs={"key_filename": "/home/user/.ssh/pkey",},)
```

And error:

`paramiko.ssh_exception.PasswordRequiredException: Private key file is encrypted`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per documentation says:

The `connect_kwargs.passphrase` config option is the most direct way to supply a passphrase to be used automatically.

*Quick fix:*

```
c = Connection(host="host",user="usr",connect_kwargs={"key_filename": "/home/user/.ssh/pkey", "passphrase": "demo"},)
```

[Here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/concepts/authentication.html) you can find more details. Also in [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/cli.html#cmdoption-prompt-for-login-password).

***The recommended approach*** is to export an environment variable in your shell session. e.g. `export SSH_PASSPHRASE="gongo-aso!`"

This can then be read from and used in the `connect_kwargs` options passed to the constructor for the Connection object.

```
connect_kwargs = {
    'passphrase': getenv('SSH_PASSPHRASE')
}

c = Connection('user@ip.address', connect_kwargs=connect_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/concepts/authentication.html) you can hand the passphrase over the following way:

```
c = Connection(host="host",user="usr",connect_kwargs={"key_filename": "/home/user/.ssh/pkey","passphrase":"mysecretpassphrase"},)
```